# javascript deactivate clicked text and activate non-clicked texts

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to write a JavaScript function that deactivates the clicked word and activates the deactivated words.
Initial state is that two are active and one is not.

```
<div id="10" style="white-space: pre; color: #ddd">
<a href="#" onclick="edit(10, 'one')">one</a>     
<span>two</span>     
<a href="#" onclick="edit(10, 'three')">three</a>     
</div>
```

Here is the MWE:

https://jsfiddle.net/kowalsky/xpvt214o/145934/

**EDIT**: in active I mean to be click-able, i.e., have onclick event. Deactivated means to be just span. As it is in the initial example and MWE.

I am interested in both javascript and js+jquery versions.

Comment: What do you mean "deactivate"?

Comment: What is wrong with the code you have? What problems are you encountering with it? Have you hit a roadblock? What is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your fiddle and you were on track, the problem is *the* track you chose, dealing with all those `'` and `"` and escaping them when necessary is just asking to get all tangled up in very subtle details, nevertheless the **FIRST** variant is a fix to that approach (in case you have special reasons to stick to it), while the **SECOND** is how I would do it if I were you.

**FIRST**

```js
function edit(id, text) {
 var div = $('#'+id);

  var span = div.children("span");

  var ahref =  '<a href="#" onclick="edit(' + id + ',\'' + span[0].textContent + '\')">';
  span.replaceWith(ahref + span[0].textContent + '</a>');
 var clicked = div.children(":contains(" + text + ")");  
  clicked.replaceWith("<span>"+text+"</span>"); 
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="10" style="white-space: pre; color: #ddd">
<a href="#" onclick="edit(10, 'one')">one</a>     
<span>two</span>     
<a href="#" onclick="edit(10, 'three')">three</a>     
</div>
```

**SECOND** (recommended)

```js
$('div').on('click', 'a', function(){
  var anchor = $(this);
  var span = $(this).siblings('span');
  anchor.replaceWith(span.clone().text(anchor.text()));
  span.replaceWith(anchor.clone().text(span.text()));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="10" style="white-space: pre; color: #ddd">
<a href="#">one</a>     
<span>two</span>     
<a href="#">three</a>     
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery `replaceWith` function to achive this.

```js
function edit(ele) {      
    $(".myClass.deactive").replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<a/>', {
        class: 'myClass',
        html: this.innerHTML,
        href:"#",
        onclick:"edit($(this))"
    }); });
    ele.replaceWith(function () {
    return $('<span/>', {
        class: 'myClass deactive',
        html: this.innerHTML        
    }); });
   
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="10" style="white-space: pre; color: #ddd">
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="edit($(this))">one</a>     
<span class="myClass deactive">two</span>     
<a href="#" class="myClass" onclick="edit($(this))">three</a>     
</div>
```